# Python reload module

Tags: python, testing

I'm writing unit-tests for a python module `module`, using python's unittest framework.

This module does a little "pre-proccessing" using a json file when it is loaded so it has things like:
`module.info['xyz']` that can be accessed and used.

When writing tests for this I want to reload the module before every test so that for every test the older keys of the dictionary `module.info` are no longer present before starting the current test.

Right now I have a `reload(module)` in `setUp()` but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I sitll have old keys introduced by `test_A` in other tests such as `test_B` and `test_C` that are executed after it.

I'd like to know if there's a way to do what I'm trying to achieve, or if you can point me to documentation that says it can not be done.

Comment: Please see the discussion here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module

Comment: @MaximKhesin I've gone through that question before posting this one, which part of the discussion do you feel answers my question?

Answer (score 2):

Manually deleting the module from the `sys.modules` dictionary seems to work for me.

```
import sys
import unittest
import myModule

class MyTest( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        global myModule
        myModule = __import__( 'path.to.myModule', globals(), locals(), [''], -1 )
        return

    def tearDown( self ):
        global myModule
        del sys.modules[myModule.__name__]
        return
```

Comment: Why are you using `__import__()` in `setUp()` rather than just `import myModule` again? If this is to maintain `myModule` in the global namespace, is there a simpler way that does not require knowing how to use `__import__()`?

Comment: Also, the `return` calls for `setUp` and `tearDown` are redundant. Methods and functions have an implied `return None` if execution falls off the end without hitting a `return` call.

Comment: I'm using `__import__()` is because it accepts a string variable which can be provided at runtime.
The `return` calls are redundant but I liked to use them as a visual cue that a functiion ends.

Comment: Instead of `del sys.modules[myModule.__name__]` you can simply do: `reload(myModule)` or `importlib.reload(myModule)` in python3